# Django - How to use a filter with a foreign key field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to do this:

```
LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type='visitor')
```

Where LogEntry is my model and content_type is a ForeignKey field pointing to another table with field id, and content_type (varchar).

How can I search by the value of the other table?  When I try to run the above it says:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'visitor'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, found it in another SO answer.  Weird it didn't seem to be documented.  Or I just skimmed over it.

Answer:

```
LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type__name='visitor')
```