# How to filter by foreign key in GenericRelation?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here are my models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...
    distributor_links = GenericRelation(Relation, related_query_name="distributor_persons")

class Model2(models.Model):
    ...
    distributor_links = GenericRelation(Relation, related_query_name="distributor_groups")

class Model3(models.Model):
    pass

class Relation(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(Model3)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Now I'd like to get all `Model1` or `Model2` object associated with Model3 object. My query looks like this:

```
Model1.objects.filter(distributor_links=self.object)
```

where `self.object` is a `Model3` instance.
The query throws an error: `Cannot query "query": Must be "Relation" instance`
I understand why it throws this error. Here `distributor_links=self.object` can't compare `Relation` object with `Model3` object but still I don't know how to write the query that I want. Any ideas?

Comment: You have filtered by self.object. What is the object?

Comment: @kari-antti, as I said, object is an instance of Model3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `self.object` is a `Model3` instance, you could:

```
Model1.objects.filter(distributor_links__link=self.object)
```

This quiestion is similar to: [Django - How to use a filter with a foreign key field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517314/django-how-to-use-a-filter-with-a-foreign-key-field)

> That is, the name of the field, followed by a double underscore (__), followed by the name of the field in the new model, and so on for as many models as you want to join.

For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: I thought about much more harder thing than using lookup expressions. This works ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to resolve ContentType of object and use it and object id for filtering.

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.object)

Model1.objects.filter(distributor_links__content_type=content_type, distributor_links__object_id=self.object.id)
```